# modelmapper skip nested object's properties

Tags: java, properties, nested, skip, modelmapper

```
class A {               class ADto {
   int id;      ->         int id;
   List<B> b;              List<BDto> b;
}                       }   

class B {               class BDto {
   int id;      ->         int id;
   C c;                    CDto c;
}                       }
```

While converting `A -> ADto`, I want to skip mapping of `C -> CDto`.
I was under the impression the following mapper would work whenever there is conversion between `B -> BDto`, which doesn't seem to be the case; so the following mapper didn't help while coverting `(A -> ADto)`...

```
class BMap extends PropertyMap<B, BDto> {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        skip(destination.getC());
    }
}
```

What should be the way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715759/lazy-initialization-exception-in-model-mapper

Answer (score 4):

In this case you could have two different options.

#### 1) Use a ModelMapper instance with a Property Map B to BDto skiping c

The first one is use a ModelMapper instance for this special case which adding the PropertyMap skiping `c` in `B -> BDto` mapping. So you must add it:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.addMappings(new BMap());
```

#### 2) Create a Converter and use it in A to ADto PropertyMap

The other option is using a converter, so in your case you should has a `Converter` to convert `B -> BDto` and then in the `A -> ADto` `PropertyMap` use it:

```
 public class BToBDto implements Converter<B, BDto> {
      @Override
      public BDtoconvert(MappingContext<B, BDto> context) {
          B b = context.getSource();
          BDto bDto = context.getDestination();
         //Skip C progammatically....
         return bDto ;
      }
 }
```

Then use the Converter in your PropertyMap:

```
    class BMap extends PropertyMap<B, BDto> {
          @Override
          protected void configure() {
                using(new BToBDto()).map(source).setC(null);
                //Other mappings...
          }
   }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more or maybe some example ?
The problem with the skip sentence is that is skips object assignment, but is assigns all the object properties individually.